# Surround code block with curly braces?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper, resharper-2016

Is there a shortcut to surround a given (selected) code block with curly braces?

VS 2015 + R# 2016.1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As an as an alternative to Patrick's answer (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>7</kbd>) you could also use the extended <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> -menu of ReSharper 9+.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>UP</kbd>, <kbd>UP</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, "bl", <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: Screen]

Unfortunately, I don't know a way to bind this to a shorter hotkey.

But if this is really important to you, you could try [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/).

Comment: Thanks, guess I'll give the "ALT+ENTER bl ENTER" a try. Hopefully https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-101338 is reopened...

Comment: done in 2017.3: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-101338#comment=27-2529794

Comment: FYI: You can do this out of the box in QtCreator by simply typing the opening curly brace (or parenthesis, quote, etc) while a block of text is selected. I miss this so much when having to work with VS.

Comment: @EmileCormier you can do it in any IDE or editor I've ever used besides VS. Even its younger sibling, VS Code, has it. Even Firefox's browser console has it! I don't understand how they could be missing this basic feature.

Comment: Thanks for Alt+Enter, plain VS has that option there now VS2022

Comment: It's honestly comical how hard they make this for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 44):

You do not need Resharper for this. You can use the "surround with" with a custom snippet.

Then you can select your text with Ctrl + K, Ctrl + S and select the snippet {} in the custom snippet. In order to create such a snippet :

1. Create a ".snippet" file containing the content below
2. Go to the snippet manager (Tools > Code Snippets Manager)
3. Click import and select the file you just created

Use the following snippet :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
 <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
  <Header>
   <Title>{}</Title>
   <Shortcut>{}</Shortcut>
   <Description>Code snippet for {}</Description>
   <Author>Alexandre</Author>
   <SnippetTypes>
    <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
    <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
   </SnippetTypes>
  </Header>
  <Snippet>
   <Code Language="csharp">
    <![CDATA[{ 
    $selected$ $end$ 
    }]]>
  </Code>
  </Snippet>
 </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I think you forgot the following two closing tags at the end:  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>

Comment: @WendelinReich Indeed, forgot the spaces in the code indentation, now corrected!  please vote for my answer if you like it, it encourages me to answer

Comment: I wanted to push it further and add specific keybind for it. I simply couldnt. So only combination Ctrl+K Ctr+S and double Tab, works for me now.
 Is there way around it?

Comment: It is faster to cut the code add one `{` it will automatically create the closing bracket then paste it. +1 cause this solution works but I am using my old technique where I copy and paste it inside braces.

Comment: The solution of  **AlexanderG** is Great, but you must put snippets in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#` as was wrote by **baobab159** below. If you put it in standard place, proposed by VS (`My Code Snippets`), in will unuseful, because you can't use the quick shortcuts - **CTRL + K + S + {} and after TAB**. (In other case, you will must at First, by mouse, select the catalog of the snippet `My Code Snippets` and after select the snippet self, It is terrible design and is brokening the Idea of use shortcuts)

Answer (score 13):

The quickest built-in shortcut in the Visual Studio scheme I can find is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>7</kbd> (surround with..., then choose option 7 which is curly braces).

I don't see a shortcut for it in Visual Studio's keyboard options, so that may be the best you can get.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 doesn't seem to have the curly braces option in the surround with menu.

Comment: There is an option for this under C/C++ > Advanced options, under the Text Editor grouping at the bottom. But it doesn't seem to affect the C# editor.

Comment: This doesn't work in Visual Studio 2019 either. Pressing Ctrl+E starts a keyboard chord and doesn't open the Surround with... menu.

Answer (score 8):

At least in Visual Studio 2019, this is a built-in optional feature, albeit it is:

1. Disabled by default
2. Buried deep in the Options

To enable this feature, select *Tools* → *Options* to open the Options dialog. In the left-hand pane that shows the options groups, expand the *Text Editor* group, then expand the *C/C++* sub-group, then select the *Advanced* item. Now scroll all the way to the bottom of the right-hand pane and you'll see the following options under the *Text Editor* section:

| Option | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Enable Surround with Braces | False |
| Enable Surround with Parentheses | False |

Change both of those to "True" (assuming you want both behaviors) and you're good to go!

Comment: These options don't seem to be available for the C# text editor.

Comment: Once you enable the above options, you can highlight text and press '{' to automatically surround the selected text with curly braces, or '(' for parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

**AlexandreG**'s solution works great. From my side I can tell you have to save the file with .snippet extension. And 2nd tip: if you want to save a snippets together with system snippets you must save them here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#`   or copy location from snippets file dialog

Answer (score 2):

I am using the [Auto Surround](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=reduckted.AutoSurround) extension in Visual Studio 2022. It's easy to use, simple, and requires no configuration or snippets.

here is how to set it up:

1. Install it from [**this link**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=reduckted.AutoSurround)
2. Reopen Visual studio
3. Select code block that you want to surround.
4. Press '{' or '(' or '['.The extension will automatically surround the selected code with the pressed symbol.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34879804)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

using visual studio 2017 with resharper 2017, it seems like the way to do this would be to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>  and either: <kbd>Up</kbd>,<kbd>Up</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd> , or start typing the shortcut name (`swb` will match `Surrond With block` and make you happy.

I'm not 100% sure if this is VS or RS though, since the  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> is VS 2017.
On the plus side, you can easily search for shortcuts and find new gems once you've hit the  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> combo.

**Update**
This is part of Resharper. I'm using 2017.1.1 ultimate. You can find more surround with templates on their page for [live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Templates_Explorer__Surround_Templates_CSHARP.html#Surround_%7B%7D_CSHARP).

Comment: Tried VS17 and R# 2017.1 -> CTRL+E is R# on my side, and swb does not work at all :-(

Comment: @D.R. Hmmm ... Tried with VS 2017 + code maid ... no love ... CTRL+K,CTRL+S will give you surround with options, but none for block. you can use any of the close enough ones (`using` for example) and simply change it, but yeah, not worth it if you can just type the brackets.

Comment: This is ridiculous that VS can't do this. MonoDevelop does it automatically when you press the { key.

Comment: @KyleDelaney sublime does as well. visual code does as well ..(both for curly and normal braces) .... :)

Answer (score 0):

This feature was just added to Visual Studio. From version `17.9` you can enable  "Auto Surround with Quotes or Brackets" from `Text Editor` settings. Then you can select a block and just type a curly brace to surround the entire block.
See [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-17-9-now-available/#auto-surround-with-quotes-or-brackets) blog post for details.