# How to use hotkeys to add a pair of curley brackets around a variable in visual studio?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, editor, hotkeys

In Javascript/ Typescript, because I need modify all default import to be non-default import, I need to add curly brackets around the original import efficiently for these are modifications in a large scale.

originally,

```js
import UserComponent from './someFile'
```

and becomes

```js
import {UserComponent} from './someFile'
```

Are there any hotkeys to add automatically the close curly bracket when I enter the open curly bracket?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37029149/surround-code-block-with-curly-braces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No
But you can select text and simple press "Shift + { " To add brackets

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the available code snippets in VS using the Code Snippets Manager - first answer on this post: [Surround code block with curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37029149/surround-code-block-with-curly-braces)